# Kotlin - adding map function conditionally

Tags: kotlin

I would like to feature toggle a map function on a list. I have a map that I would like to run only if the feature is on:
So for something like this:

```
items
     .map { doTransformation(it) } 
     .map { runOnlyIfFeatureIsOn(it) }
```

Is there a way of adding the whole `.map` function conditionally in kotlin, so that it is only there if it is feature toggled?

Comment: And whether or not the feature is on is determined at runtime? What would be the _type_ of the result then? Would it be the type after the transformation, or the type before the transformation? See how this doesn't make sense now?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you have example input/output? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`let()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html) is handy for doing arbitrary processing in a pipeline, e.g.:

```
items
    .map{ doTransformation(it) } 
    .let{ if (someCondition) it.map{ runOnlyIfFeatureIsOn(it) } else it }
```

(For complex/costly conditions, this will be more efficient  than putting the `if` inside the `map` call, as this'll only evaluate the condition once.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just do if in map? There is no problem with that:

```kotlin
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3)

    list
        .map { it * 2 }
        .map {
            if (featureIsOn) {
                runFeatureMapping(it)
            } else {
                it
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sequences:

```
var sequence = items.asSequence()
    .map { doTransformation(it) }

if (<feature_1_enabled>) {
    sequence = sequence.map { runOnlyIfFeature1IsOn(it) }
}

if (<feature_2_enabled>) {
    sequence = sequence.map { runOnlyIfFeature2IsOn(it) }
}

val result = sequence.toList()
```

Sequences are lazy-evaluated and should be used when mutliple operations (filter/map/etc) are applied